# Using both Facebook Graph API and Old Rest API? Please help!

Tags: facebook, rest, graph

I am developing a Facebook application that will use Facebook events.
I want to be able to create and edit event as well as invite users friends to the event.

I prefer to use the new Graph API to handle all connections with Facebook and I many ways I am able too, but, the Graph API cannot send invites.

I saw that the Old Rest API got far more ways to interact with Facebook so I tried to use both systems on the same time but when I send the Access token that I have created with the Graph API a long with a call to the old API it says "Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token".

My question is, is there a way to convert the new Graph API access token to be used with the old rest API? Is there perhaps another way to get both systems to work in the same application?

Please help! All input are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I´d recommend against the old REST api. Support will be canceled sooner or later and then you will have to port to graph api anyway.

To send invites to your app you can use fbml/xfbml. try the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector togehter with the JavaScript SDK as described here: http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/jssdk/learning_jssdk_11.html

good luck!